# AIX text formatting

Tags: bash, aix

AIX Version 6.1

I'm trying to write a script to pull times out of a program to send to Zabbix, but I'm wanting to modify the formatting of the times returned.

At present, when I pull the time it returns like so: [15:48:30]

My goal is to remove the brackets ([]) to then be able to pull the time apart with awk to do calculations on the time to render it down into seconds and draw relevant information from that.

AIX is continually giving me errors with every form of text formatting I can think of/find.

Ex: `echo $unformattedtime | awk '{print substr($0,1,8)}'`

gives me permissions errors when I've already chmod 777 the script. I've seen fixes that require going in and making root changes, and while that's possible for me to do, the script needs to run as a non-root user for what it's being designed to do.

Failing manipulating the unformattedtime variable, I tried putting it into a text file and manipulating it with tr.

Ex: `tr -s [] '' < timet.txt > timetformat.txt`

Where timet.txt simply had the '[15:48:30]' put in using vi. This simply returned a "tr:Error 0"

Is there some sort of AIX specific method of doing modifications that I'm missing? Or just anything that would accomplish the goal here?

Thanks!

Comment: What permission errors did that `awk` version give you exactly? Nothing in that line involves an external script. Does quoting `"$unformattedtime"` help there? Similarly does quoting `'[]'` help the `tr` option? (Also did you want `-d` there instead of `-s` since `-s` would leave single square brackets alone.)

Comment: The Awk version was giving me errors saying that I didn't have permission to execute the script. The tr -d method works for me though, and having a few text files to clean up at the end of a script won't be an issue, so I'll go ahead and use that method, thanks for the help!

Comment: Depending on the shell you have available you might be able to avoid the files by redirecting to tr from a `HEREDOC`. `tr -d '[]' <<EOF\necho "$unformattedtime"\nEOF` or so.

Comment: Even better! Excellent, thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from my comments:

`tr -s` is going to leave single square brackets unmolested, this isn't what you want. (Though I don't understand that error unless it is a quoting issue on `[]` in the shell. Try `'[]'` instead.)

`tr -d '[]'` is probably more what you want there.

It might also be possible, depending on the shell, to avoid the temporary files by using a `HEREDOC`:

```
tr -d '[]' <<EOF
echo "$unformattedtime"
EOF
```

There can be *no* leading spaces before the final `EOF` there for the record.